# How can one toggle a list of items using a button in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to filter a list of items based on certain criteria using a toggle button. Let's say that our list is a list of, say, programmers, each of whom knows java, javascript, or both java and javascript. To start, we have a list of all programmers and a toggle switch that says "knows java" and another that says "knows javascript," we take the original list and filter it such that we return either programmers who know java or those who know javascript, depending on the toggle pressed. Though there are two different filters, both can be pressed at a time, and it will return the entire original list. If no button is pressed, the entire original list of programmers displays as well. So far I'm working on just one toggle, whose functionality technically works but is bugged. Here's some code to demonstrate:

```
    handleToggleJavaProgrammersClick = () => {
    const { programmers } = this.state;
    // let's assume that programmers is an array of objects with the boolean properties
    // knowsJava and knowsJavascript
    const javaOnlyProgrammers = programmers.filter(
        (programmer) => !!programmer.knowsJava && !programmer.knowsJavascript,
    );

    this.setState({
        programmers: javaOnlyProgrammers;
    })

    return javaOnlyProgrammers;
};
```

Then when we render a button component, its onClick property takes in `this.handleToggleJavaProgrammersClick`. The issue is, say we want to do the same sort of function for `handleToggleJavascriptProgrammersClick`. Then when we set the state of `programmers` to `javascriptOnlyProgrammers`, it will take the current state, which is our filtered list of programmers who know only java, and just filter it further; it will never return to the original list, and only filter ad infinitum.

Is there a way to accomplish this without setting state all of the time? Perhaps set a boolean to determine if the button is clicked or not? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't return values from handlers, handlers are mostly void functions. In react applications, the state will dictate how the UI should look like. So just read the state where you need it

Answer (score 0):

Why not add a new value to your state like, `javaOnlyProgrammers`?

```
class Toggler extends Component {
  state = {
    programmers: [],
    javaOnlyProgrammers :[]
  }
}
```

Then in your click handler filter like you've been doing. Instead of returning the javaOnlyProgrammers, `setState`:

```
handleToggleJavaProgrammersClick = () => {
  this.setState({
    javaOnlyProgrammers: this.state.programmers.filter(
        (programmer) => !!programmer.knowsJava && !programmer.knowsJavascript,
    );
  });
};
```